# Заблокировать порт 80 на определенном IP

Tags: route, lan, mikrotik

На хосте `192.168.88.55` у меня висит сайт (слушает порт 80). Теперь я хочу заблокировать доступ к этому хосту по порту `80`.

Создал правило

```
ip firewall filter> add chain=forward dst-address=192.168.88.55 protocol=tcp dst-port=80 action=drop
```

но это не сработало - сайт все-равно открывается при вводе в браузере (любой машины в сети) `195.168.88.55:80`.

Что не так?

Comment: Сайт открывается из внутренней сети (из локалки) или из внешней (Интернет)?

Comment: @kff, из внутренней.

Comment: Трафик, не выходящий за пределы внутренней сети ходит по встроенному в Mikrotik коммутатору и функции маршрутизации при этом не используются. Файрволл работает только при маршрутизации, т.е. при передаче трафика между разными сетями.

Comment: @kff, то есть осуществить блокировку порта, мне необходимо при помощи уже программных `сетевых сканеров` на подобии `KIS`? На самом деле мне нужно заблокировать этот порт только от некоторых машин сети.

Comment: Да. Только KIS - не сканер, а антивирус+файрволл. И это можно сделать и без KIS. Нужный функционал присутствует даже в стандартном брандмауэре Windows.